# Sum up every digit in UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm new to Swift and trying a little numerology app. The problem is, how to add every single-digit numbers of the date of birth? I have a text field, where a user enters his date of birth and then after clicking on the button, it should return the result of the sum in a label in another VC.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: get the text field text and map through each character and convert it to the number and sum it. and pass it to next VC to show onto the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Let's say you have following date string in your text field.**

```
var dateString = "19/09/2018"

let sum = dateString.reduce(0) { (res, char) -> Int in
    var res = res
    if let number = Int(String(char)) {
       res+=number
    }
    return res
}

print(sum) ==> 30
```

**And using segue method you can just pass this sum to your next VC.**

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) { }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm ashamed to admit,  but I didn't know about reduce function. I've only assigned a datePicker as the inputView and didn't know what to do next. Thanks again! I hope it will work.

Comment: @Abrcd18 it will definitely work. Please mark my answer correct if it worked. :)